# how to set css attribute type "top" , with thymeleft value in html

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aixdK.png)

I want to set button css attribute :top,  with thymeleaf value positionIndex.x
how can i do that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace the screenshot of code with formatted text. [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).  Why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you tried? What happened when you tried it? Show us any errors you get (as formatted text).